how to install ansible-core 2.16 in debian
I am new to ansible but looking for instructions how to install ansible-core 2.16 with no luck.
So looking if you can share the instructions to install ansible-core 2.16 in debian
Here are the outputs:
ansible [core 2.14.3]
config file = None
sudo apt install ansible-core
ansible-core is already the newest version (2.14.3-1).

Most OS distribution repositories are always behind what the current release is for a package. This is true for many common packages like perl, php, etc...

If you can't get what you want by following official docs Installing Ansible on Debian you can always Install Ansible with pip. It is recommended to install Ansible in Python virtual environments. For example, in Ubuntu 24.04, depending on the Python version you want to use, install package python3.12-venv and create the Python virtual environment
shell> sudo apt install python3.12-venv
shell> python3 -m venv env

This command will create the directory env. Activate the environment and install ansible. Optionally instal also ansible-lint and ansible-runner
shell> source env/bin/activate
(env) >  python -m pip install ansible
(env) >  python -m pip install ansible-lint
(env) >  python -m pip install ansible-runner

List installed packages
(env) > python -m pip list | grep ansible
ansible                   9.5.1
ansible-compat            4.1.11
ansible-core              2.16.6
ansible-lint              24.2.3
ansible-runner            2.3.6

At the moment the latest version is 2.16
(env) > ansible --version
ansible [core 2.16.6]
  config file = /home/admin/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/admin/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/admin/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/admin/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/admin/env/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.12.3 (main, Apr 10 2024, 05:33:47) [GCC 13.2.0] (/home/admin/env/bin/python)
  jinja version = 3.1.4
  libyaml = True

(env) > ansible localhost -m setup | grep ansible_distribution
        "ansible_distribution": "Ubuntu",
        "ansible_distribution_file_parsed": true,
        "ansible_distribution_file_path": "/etc/os-release",
        "ansible_distribution_file_variety": "Debian",
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "24",
        "ansible_distribution_release": "noble",
        "ansible_distribution_version": "24.04",

Deactivate the environment if you want to close it correctly
(env) > deactivate
shell> 



Note: The module ansible.builtin.pip can create the virtual environment. Quoting from the parameter virtualenv:

An optional path to a virtualenv directory to install into. It cannot be specified together with the ‘executable’ parameter (added in 2.1). If the virtualenv does not exist, it will be created before installing packages. The optional virtualenv_site_packages, virtualenv_command, and virtualenv_python options affect the creation of the virtualenv.


